# Randomized alternative to Buchberger's algorithm

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ag.algebraic-geometry, algorithms, computer-algebra, computational-complexity

Richard Lipton's blog describes a [A New Way To Solve Linear Equations](http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2012/08/09/a-new-way-to-solve-linear-equations/) by Prasad Raghavendra.

Can the ideas in this algorithm be generalized to systems of polynomial equations to provide a randomized alternative to [Buchberger's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchberger%27s_algorithm).